# Unable to download dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am start learning java and spring and following the tutorial from web. I have download the structure using https://start.spring.io/. I have problem while building the project in sts.

Below is the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.restapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>restapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restapi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am able to access UI as well.

Error :
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.restapi:restapi:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.7 failed to transfer from url.This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of virtual has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.7 from/to virtual (https://artifactory.xxx.dev/artifactory/docce-maven-dev): Connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM  pom.xml /restapi    line 5  Maven pom Loading Problem

Comment: Can you access your configured repository (e.g. by trying the UI)?

Comment: @ dunni : Yes , i am able to access

Comment: can you remove contents of spring boot jars from .m2 & try again?

Comment: Is the URL correct? Are you able to access the URL in a browser?

Comment: Looks like a network issue or your configuration to access your repository manager is not ok..

Answer (score 0):

The error says the failure was cached in the local repository. Maybe a clean install maven command could helps:

```
mvn clean install
```

You can set up in IntelliJ, if you use it:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).